# Looking for valid reasons for the downvote to this question

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I'm looking for valid reasons for the downvote to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494872/why-does-but-i-later-realized-have-no-car-seem-better-than-but-i-later-real?noredirect=1#comment1194665_494872) question.

I have raised this question, on meta, for three reasons.

1. I think the question's OK, should be answered, and I still desire an answer.
2. I want to learn how to use stackexchange, and elu stack. And,
3. I think it may reflect wider voting patters on elu stack at least.

Here is the comment I left, which asserts my present thinking on the downvote:

> i don't think this question should be downvoted. it's clear, and i
>   just won't easily find the answer. the voter seems to act like a meta
>   voter, i.e. voting down because they disagree with something said in
>   the question. that, imho, debases the use of the site, as well as
>   being a misuse of it

It has now received comments from four users myself included, and a vote to close for being off-topic (!). So, I think the issue *is* relevant, even if the meta question doesn't have wider appeal.

It seems that the question is being voted as "off-topic". But, also, that I am unable to convince anyone it is, despite not understanding how at all it could be!

Cheers!

Comment: i received an upvote right after i edited the phrase "why does this sound better" to explicitly mean that that's why i think it's grammatical. so, i'm guessing that's the reason for the two votes in question! my own inability to phrase questions **clearly**

Comment: Wasn't the question downvoted before you added the context needed to answer it?

Comment: it turns out that way, that's why, yes @Laurel ... i didn't realize that, due to thinking that it was expressing a problem of *general* interest

Comment: i have decided to always include full context to any and all questions. that *should* help @Laurel

Comment: i have edited the question a lot, and the comments were helpful to make it clear and on-topic. cheers!

Comment: 4 downvotes? Pfft, I can get something like 30 downvotes when I post something on Meta SE.

Comment: Is your shift key broken now? Or does it just not work with 'i'?

Comment: you all just seem hostile at this point @Mitch

Comment: i don't understand why this question has SEVEN downvotes when the main question isn't that bad (just one downvote and one upvote on ELL)

Answer (score 2):

Down-votes are like mosquitoes: You can watch them alight and then blow them off, or you can slap at them and make a bloody mess. Best solution is to put on a good repellent.

Comment: I like the analogy! For me they're more like sunburn: when you're young (low-rep) it hurts more and happens more often, but if you love the outdoors you don't let it stop you, you just learn to take more care. In your middle years it's still a bit annoying but doesn't seem to sting as much, and in your later years (high-rep) - well, I haven't got there yet, so I won't presume to guess what it's like ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the requirement to show research, earn downvotes.

Comment: Let's pretend the OP is not a linguist, how would they go about researching the answer to that question? And the OP actually provided a link about [pronoun dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language#English), so some research was in fact made.

Comment: @Mari they'd ask a native English speaker they know in real life.

Comment: oh please, what sort of reason to downvote is that!

Comment: @user3293056 Probably the most common? I mean it's widely regarded as the number one problem of poor questions on this site.

Comment: @user3293056 It's also literally the meaning of the downvote button, hover over it to see "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: do you think that most english language speakers know what pro-drop even is?

Comment: i get the desire for conformity etc., something you dannii, especially, seem to enjoy. but the group think here seems too much

Comment: @user3293056 No. Many of the users on this site will. However it's not really what the question was about, which was a simple grammaticality judgement. If you had two similar sentences, one grammatical, one not, then it could be interesting to ask how pro-drop made a difference.

Comment: you're completely unable to see things from other people's point of view.

Comment: i mean, you're right that it can be answered without reference to pro-drop. but the sentence can't i think be shown to be wrong without reference to pro-drop, which was the intention of the question (the context was just fabricated)

Comment: Then make that intention clear, rather than making it look like a garden variety grammaticality judgement question.

Comment: it *was* clear that i was asking about pro-drop, though i guess i could have gone further to show it was the reason for asking